# which kind of part of speech does the following phrase function as?

Tags: american-english, adverbial-phrases

> I am not the type of woman who sits home waiting for a man

I expect that the phrase *"waiting for a man"* functions as an adjective modifying the *woman* here. But sometimes, in such a case, it makes me think *"waiting for a man"* functions as an adverbial modifying the *"sits home"*.

Comment: Shouldn't it be like"i am not the type of women who waits for a man sitting home"?

Comment: *waiting for a man* is an adverbial modifying *sits*, *home* is an andverbial of location, also modifying *sits*. It is the woman who sits, not the man.

Comment: While you might say "sits home", the more formal form would be "sits *at* home". This also makes the phrases in the sentence clearer because you can treat "at home" as a prepositional phrase.

Answer (score 1):

This is a frequent pattern; the clause with the -ing form at its head complements the verb in the main clause:

He stayed home waiting for a package.

She sat in church praying for a miracle.

He stood on stage playing the trombone.

They went out searching for their dog.

He died trying.

Comment: What does "he died trying" mean? Does it mean,he try to die?

Comment: It is a shortened form of "He died trying (to do something)."

Comment: "I stayed up too late at my friends flat playing video games "  is it right?

Comment: Yes, your sentence is grammatical and natural. :)   Just a minor fix: at my *friend's* flat.